# Where do I store a connection string so it is accessible by visual studio at design time?

Tags: visual-studio, connection-string, design-time, uitypeeditor

I have some custom property editors that need to pull application data.  These are working great in my test project where I am able to set a connection string in my app.config file.  However, in actual practice, these editors will be running from within Visual Studio.  Not inside one of my applications.  Where can I store my connection string so that it is itself data (so I can have different values in different environments), and accessible to my custom editors within visual studio at design time?

I was thinking I might be able to leverage the server explorer.  But I'm not really sure how to create a 'global context' with the server explorer, and then have all my controls have access to it while being designed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't completed this yet, but I think the answer is to create a visual studio extension, set these values there, and then just have my controls expect that extension to be present at design time.  This will be a very small, controlled environment, so that should work fine.